# Why does buildroot automatically remove manually added in-tree package from .config when make is run?

Tags: buildroot

I've added a simple hello world package to the Buildroot source tree under `package/hello`.

If I do:

```
 make qemu_x86_64_defconfig
```

and edit `.config` with `vim` to add:

```
 BR2_PACKAGE_HELLO=y
```

then:

```
make
```

the package gets installed.

But if I look again at the `.config`, it has been modified, and `BR2_PACKAGE_HELLO=y` was removed.

How to prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

Add a line of type:

```
source "package/hello/Config.in"
```

to:

```
package/Config.in
```

under the appropriate `menu`.

`make` runs `make oldconfig`, which updates `.config`, and removes any unknown options not present in one of the known `Config.in` files.